# RIP actress Kirstie Alley

Tags: discussion, in-memoriam

Kirstie Alley, known for many roles including Saavik in *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Khan*, has passed away from cancer. She was 71.

> Alley's children, True and Lillie Parker, announced the actress had died from cancer. In a statement to PEOPLE, True and Lillie confirmed that Alley died on Monday.
>
> "We are sad to inform you that our incredible, fierce and loving mother has passed away after a battle with cancer, only recently discovered," they said in a statement.
>
> <sub>["Kirstie Alley Dead: Star of 'Cheers' Dies at 71 After Short Battle with Cancer" — *People*](https://people.com/tv/kirstie-alley-dead/)</sub>

Comment: Sir, may I quote General Order Twelve? 'On the approach of any vessel, when communications have not been established -' If only Kirk had listened.

Comment: not just beautiful with stage presence but i think she showed herself to be very sharp on one of those word-game tv shows.